# I am getting the error ‘ Error: The variable result in a parfor cannot be classified.’

Tags: matlab, gpu

I use matlab.

```
matlabpool

% key code

result=zeros(size(I,1)-2*l-1,size(I,2)-2*width-1,num_of_dir);
s1=size(I,1);
s2=size(I,2);
parfor t=1:num_of_dir
    for i=l+1:size(I,1)-l-1
        for j=width+1:size(I,2)-width-1

            result(i,j,t)=wilcoxon(I,i,j,temple{t},alpha,sigma);

        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252758).
The problem is in you inner for loop indices. You cannot use `size(I,1)` or `size(I,2)`.
If you replace them with the variables `s1` and `s2` that appear in your code it should work.